# C trouble with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

In this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun (int *x, int i) {
 int r;
 printf("%d\n", *(x+i/2));
 r = *x + i / 2 + *(x + i / 2);
 return r;
}
int main (void) {
 int x[] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
 printf("%d", fun(x, 7));
 return 0;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding, why is *(x+i/2) = 5?

Comment: Note that `i / 2` uses integer division....

Comment: What value do you think it should be, and why?

Comment: `*(x+i/2) = 5` because `8,4 * 5 = 42`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*(x)` would be the first element of the array, 8.
`*(x+i/2) == *(x+7/2) == *(x+3) == x[3] == 5`

Note
a) integer division (rounding down)
b) pointer arithmetic, `*(x+1)` is looking at second array entry, not second byte

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful.

Comment: My pleasure. Here is more helpful information, especially on how different aspects of StackOverflow work, how they are supposed to be used and what to do in certain situations: [tour] I bet there is something matching exactly the situation you are currently experiencing.